# Enable multithreading to use std::thread: Operation not permitted

Tags: linux, arch-linux, xorg

I typically only use linux machines for work, they tend to be older under powered machines. I actually have arch linux on a beefer machine and decided to try my hand at running a game on it. I downloaded the [office management 101 demo](https://tulevikeu.itch.io/office-management-101) to see if I could get it to run. I unzipped it, got into the folder and ran `$ chmod a+x OfficeManagement101` and then:

```
$ ./OfficeManagement101 
config file: /home/me/Downloads/om101-linux/config.json
jar: /home/me/Downloads/om101-linux/om101_drm_free.jar
mainClass: eu/tulevik/officemanagement101/desktop/DesktopLauncher
vmArg 0: -Xmx1G
jre: /home/me/Downloads/om101-linux/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so
Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglGraphics.setVSync(LwjglGraphics.java:555)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run(LwjglApplication.java:122)
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.LinuxDisplay.getAvailableDisplayModes(LinuxDisplay.java:954)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.LinuxDisplay.init(LinuxDisplay.java:738)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.<clinit>(Display.java:138)
    ... 2 more
AL lib: (EE) alc_cleanup: 1 device not closed
```

Some digging around the internet has me do `$ sudo pacman -S xorg-xrandr`, the screen fades to black but then I get a new error:

```
$ ./OfficeManagement101 
config file: /home/me/Downloads/om101-linux/config.json
jar: /home/me/Downloads/om101-linux/om101_drm_free.jar
mainClass: eu/tulevik/officemanagement101/desktop/DesktopLauncher
vmArg 0: -Xmx1G
jre: /home/me/Downloads/om101-linux/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::system_error'
  what():  Enable multithreading to use std::thread: Operation not permitted
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Which leaves me without a real good idea of what to do next, is this something I need to fix in linux is this a c++ issue a little from both, any help?

Comment: You are trying to use C++11 multithreading, but I doubt that your Linux is recent enough to support it.

Comment: @harrymc so what should I do about this demo just be out of luck, it is fine if that is the answer, I just want to know.

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7132549/165358) to determine your installed C++ version.

Comment: @harrymc: nonsense, GCC would not give an error saying how to use std::thread if it didn't support it.

Comment: @JonathanWakely: Welcome here, but you are barging in on a post that is 4 years old...

Comment: Yes, to answer an unanswered question. That's how SE works.

Answer (score 1):

> what():  Enable multithreading to use std::thread: Operation not permitted

This means the program (or some part of it) was not linked using  GCC's `-pthread` option that links to the Pthreads implementation in Glibc.

This *might* work, but really the correct solution is for the program to be properly built with the `-pthread` option:

```
LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib64/libpthread.so.0 ./OfficeManagement101
```